# SSJS DataExtension.Add Syntax for Decimal Fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, ssjs

I need to create a data extension using javascript that includes DECIMAL fields.

Here's my code that wasn't working.

```
var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "Genesis_DE",
        "Name" : "Genesis_DE",
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "OppID", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
          { "Name" : "MemSvngs", "FieldType" : "Decimal", "MaxLength" : 15.2 },
        ]
    };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
```

I was pretty sure the issue was with the DECIMAL field. Specifically, I didn’t think the syntax for the MaxLength parameter was correct. But, I couldn’t find documentation on what the right format is.

What's the correct syntax for defining a decimal field in Marketing Cloud using SSJS DataExtension.Add method? The documentation from SF doesn't offer any help here and I'm a SSJS beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the right parameter to use in the JSON is "Scale". So the code that ended working is...

```
var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "Genesis_DE",
        "Name" : "Genesis_DE",
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "OppID", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
          { "Name" : "MemSvngs", "FieldType" : "Decimal", "MaxLength" : 15, "Scale" : 2 },
        ]
    };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
```